# Where is the toolbar XML layout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'd like to change the toolbar height, but I searched everywhere in my app, can only found a menu XML which contains items.

I am a beginner.
I've refer to other questions, they have a XML like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

I confirmed no such widget in my app, but my app did show the toolbar with menu.
How can I get the toolbar XML layout, then I will look for how to change its height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your values/styles.xml file change this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To use a *NoActionBar* parent theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then you will be able to use your own Toolbar in xml files.

Comment: If I use system's DarkActionBar, how to change its height? Thx.

Comment: Using systems's DarkActionBar, you can't actually change its height.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this line on activity onCreate()

```
this.window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

or You can define a new style within values/styles.xml so it looks like this

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Then You can able to create your own toolbar layout in XML.